# App store - buying with paypal through iPhone

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, paypal

Question is simple, how to use paypal as payment method? I don't know is this important, but I am no-U.S. citizen.

I suppose this is possible, just look at the link: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631 but there is no details about how to use it. I know there is paypal app, so if anybody have experience with that app, can answer too.

Mainly I would like to buy apps from the appstore via paypal. My debit card is connected with my paypal account. I know I can use debit/ credit card information to buy, but that defeats whole purpose of having an paypal account. I guess this can be easily done, but I just can't find paypal option on my iPhone's app store app...

Comment: It's not available in all countries. If available, you will be able to change it on [https://appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com).

Comment: Hi jherran, you probably meant changing payment options trough iTunes Store account (Apple ID) under payment options, but I get it...

Comment: Login into your account in iTunes, see if you can change it.